# Do I need visa for Poland with UK refugee travel documents?

Tags: visas, uk, air-travel, poland, refugees

I want make sure that I can go to Poland for holiday with out visa because I have UK refugee travel documents. I need help because I try to ask the Poland consulate but I didn’t find an answer please help ASAP.

Comment: You can check entry requirements via the [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/) website (scroll down through ‘nationality’ to *stateless persons / refugees*. I believe you need a visa

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is no. The reason is that looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area (from [this EU source](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/information-national-derogations-visa-requirement_en)), there is a section for people with refugee travel documents. Under Poland, it says

> Czech Republic, Poland: refugees in Ireland

and hence you're not covered. You would if you were travelling to the Netherlands though (but cannot travel to Poland legally in that case, despite the presence of open borders, according to [ind.nl](https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/visa-the-netherlands/refugees-stateless)).